# Generating high quality images of the TensorBoard Projector

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

Given a visualization in TensorBoard is there any possibility to create a high resolution image from the viewport?

The aim is an asthetic image so a 2D plot using matplotlib sadly is not ideal. But the 3D rendering is already there so I am hoping there is a way, TensorBoard related or not. However, the viewport of the Projector is too small for a simple screenshot. Any ideas would be absolutely awesome.

Edit:
As the appearance of the projector substantially changes at resolutions beyond  4k (and why shouldn't it) getting screenshots with Chrome's Developer Interface does not work.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?